# Do children Forms run on the same thread of the main Form by default?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, .net-4.5

If I create a child `Form` will it operate on the same thread as it's parent `Form`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  You have to go very far out of your way to load a child form in a separate thread

Comment: Thank you, I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before.
I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me :)

Comment: @Enigmativity Would it be possible to *create* a form on a new thread, though?

Comment: @ReousaAsteron - You have to create a completely new message pump. The two forms would run independently of each other. It's not easy.

Answer (score 0):

They **must** run on the same thread as their parent. So, yes, it happens by default. If you do manage to create a child `Form` on a different thread then it's very likely to crash your program.